# Active_Skin with ActiveAdmin using CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, cancan

I am using cancan to manage authorizations in an activeadmin environment. I have recently used the [active_skin](https://github.com/KMPgroup/active_skin) gem to improve the looks, but only the super admin with manage:all access could see the new looks. May I know how I could make it visible to others?

Here is a sample Ability file:

```
if user.is? :admin
      can :manage, :all
else
      # Admin users can only manage their own posts
      can :manage, Post, :organization_id => user.organization_id 
end
```

Comment: Hi -put in a answer below - did it help ?  Pierre

Answer (score 1):

1- You can use this
can :read, :all
2- Suggest you use new CanCanCan asCanCan no longer updated.  Switching is no drama
Pierre

Comment: Hi Pierre, Thanks for the answer. Using CanCanCan is certainly a helpful hint. One problem is that I do not want all the admins to see all the models. Only the master admin should see some capabilities. :read, :all will not give that result then.

Comment: Hi NRR -have had another at the question in which I use the username attribute to distinguish between different admin users.

Answer (score 0):

in my application for the User model I have an attribute username (should probably be name).  Username is the name the user signs in with.  In the sample code below I check if the current user is admin level and then if the username == admin they can manage all else they can only read all.  The puts statements are for checking purposes.

```
class Ability
```

include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user

```
if user
  if user.is? :admin 
    puts "-------"
    name = user.username
    puts "username = " + name.to_s
    puts "-------"
    if name == "admin"
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  elsif user.is? :user
    can :manage, Drill
```